# Swift 3 reading from network socket using 'withUnsafeBufferPointer' - 'init' unavailable use 'withMemoryRebound'

Tags: xcode, sockets, swift3

I have a function in Swift 2.3 which reads Int value from a network socket

```
open func readInt() -> Int32 {
    var intValueBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    self.stream!.read (&intValueBuffer, maxLength: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    let intValue = intValueBuffer.withUnsafeBufferPointer({
        UnsafePointer<Int32>($0.baseAddress!).pointee
    })
    return Int32(bigEndian: intValue)
}
```

After migrating to Swift 3 I'm hitting this error. I haven't been able to figure out what actually needs to change, any help would be really appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion from a pointer to `UInt8` to a pointer to `Int32`
must be made explicit with `withMemoryRebound()`:

```
func readInt() -> Int32 {
    var intValueBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    self.stream!.read(&intValueBuffer, maxLength: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    let intValue = intValueBuffer.withUnsafeBufferPointer({
        $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: Int32.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0.pointee
        }
    })
    return Int32(bigEndian: intValue)
}
```

Alternatively, read into a `Data` object instead of an array:

```
func readInt() -> Int32 {
    var intValueBuffer = Data(count: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    intValueBuffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        _ = self.stream!.read($0, maxLength: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
    }
    return Int32(bigEndian: intValueBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
}
```

or directly into an integer variable:

```
func readInt() -> Int32 {
    var intValue: Int32 = 0
    withUnsafePointer(to: &intValue) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size) {
            _ = self.stream!.read($0, maxLength: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
        }
    }
    return Int32(bigEndian: intValue)
}
```

For more information see [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html) on swift.org.

You may also want to check the return value of the `read` method
which is the number of bytes actually read, or -1 if the read operation failed.